# Magento: Where does Magento 1.8 store payment method options in the database?

Tags: database, magento, payment-gateway, payment

Where does Magento store payment method options in the database?
I looked around and did not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not talking about Paypal methods(which have named tables in database), Magento doesn't store payment methods information in database. There is a folder named payment under core/Mage, where you will find all the details regarding to the available payment methods in your magento installation in the form of files. I'd recommend starting with config.xml. Let me know if you need any more explaination on this one.